# How to apply Curve at bottom of UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I want to mask and add some curve at bottom of image view. i have try below code .

```
extension UIImage{
    var roundedImage: UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: self.size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 1)
        UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect,
            cornerRadius: self.size.height
            ).addClip()
        self.draw(in: rect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    }
  }
```

But not getting success. 
Let me put UI here that i want to show in screen. 
[image]

Let me know how to show UIImageView Like above screen shots in swift.

I have found some use full thing in android but not in iOS.

Link : [Crescento View](https://github.com/developer-shivam/Crescento)

Comment: You need to make your own `UIBezierPath` to do this, roundedRect will add border corners in your rectangle view, what you need is more specific than that

Comment: @ReinierMelian
I have no deep knowledge of   UIBezierPath if you help me with snippet of code then it will be great for me.

Comment: Answer added @JayMehta

Comment: my answer was updated @JayMehta

Answer (score 20):

As I said in my comment you need to make your own `UIBezierPath` adding a quad curve in the bottom part of your path, the `curvedPercent` will be how pronounced your curve will be, you can adjust it as you need it

**Custom UIImageView class**

```
@IBDesignable
class CurvedUIImageView: UIImageView {
    
    private func pathCurvedForView(givenView: UIView, curvedPercent:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
    {
        let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
        arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:givenView.bounds.size.height))
        arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:givenView.bounds.size.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width/2, y:givenView.bounds.size.height-givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        arrowPath.close()
        
        return arrowPath
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var curvedPercent : CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            guard curvedPercent <= 1 && curvedPercent >= 0 else{
                return
            }
            
            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: self.layer)
            shapeLayer.path = self.pathCurvedForView(givenView: self,curvedPercent: curvedPercent).cgPath
            shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds
            shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
            self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
        }
    }

}
```

**Result in Storyboard as is *Designable***

[image]
[image]
[image]

**For any kind of View, added `curvedPercent` parameter**

```
func pathCurvedForView(givenView: UIView, curvedPercent:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
    {
        let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
        arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:givenView.bounds.size.height))
        arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:givenView.bounds.size.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width/2, y:givenView.bounds.size.height-givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        arrowPath.close()
        
        return arrowPath
    }

func applyCurvedPath(givenView: UIView,curvedPercent:CGFloat) {
    guard curvedPercent <= 1 && curvedPercent >= 0 else{
        return
    }
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: givenView.layer)
    shapeLayer.path = self.pathCurvedForView(givenView: givenView,curvedPercent: curvedPercent).cgPath
    shapeLayer.frame = givenView.bounds
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
    givenView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
}
```

**How can I use it?**

```
self.applyCurvedPath(givenView: self.customView,curvedPercent: 0.5)
```

**Result for `curvedPercent = 0.5`**

[image]

**Result for `curvedPercent = 0.1`**

[image]

**Result for `curvedPercent = 0.9`**

[image]

## UPDATE

For inverted curve replace original `pathCurvedForView` method by this one

```
func pathCurvedForView(givenView: UIView, curvedPercent:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
{
    let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
    arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:0))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width, y:givenView.bounds.size.height - (givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent)))
    arrowPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:givenView.bounds.size.height - (givenView.bounds.size.height*curvedPercent)), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:givenView.bounds.size.width/2, y:givenView.bounds.size.height))
    arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
    arrowPath.close()
    
    return arrowPath
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @chiragshah appreciated

Comment: well explined answer

Comment: Thanks @LeNI appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't it make a perfect curve? Why is it more curvy at the start and less curvy at the end?

Comment: i will review it @KaranveerSingh, should be because iam using QuadCurve, i will update with findings

Comment: how can we apply it to the top of a UIView

Answer (score 4):

***This will help you to solve your problem***

```
extension UIImageView{
      var roundedImage: UIImageView {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: self.layer)
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.bounds.size.width, y:0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:self.bounds.size.width, y:self.bounds.size.height))
        bezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.size.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:self.bounds.size.width/2, y:self.bounds.size.height-self.bounds.size.height*0.3))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
        bezierPath.close()
        maskLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        return self
      }
    }
```

> **Result**

[image]

Comment: you are answer is working for only imageview otherwise it is good.