# Transform UIView shape

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform, shapes

I want to transform my UIView's shape into this (the white UIView - look at the right edge) using Swift:

[image]

Any ideas how to do it? I guess I should use the transform functionality, but I don't know how exactly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: show the code you got now

Comment: In fact, I have nothing to show, because nothing is really working near to expected. I have something that creates a parallelogram, but it's not the desired shape:

        myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: -0.3, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)

Comment: so don't even have the code for the view itself without that effect?

Comment: It's just a normal view with width = 200 and height = 20. Like in the picture.

Comment: why is it that everytime I ask for a code, instead of including the code in the question, people start explaining in the comments what the code looks like?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317569/how-to-apply-curve-at-bottom-of-uiimageview/48317771#48317771

Comment: let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 20.0))
Here it is. As I said, it's just a normal UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Here is the update, I misunderstood your question in my first answer
You need to subclass UIView and override the default draw method with your own behaviour. To Adjust the angle you can change the `offsetFactor`

```
class ShapeView : UIView {
    public var bgc = UIColor.clear
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //backup old background color
        self.bgc = backgroundColor!
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.bgc = backgroundColor!
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let size = self.bounds.size

        let offsetFactor = size.width * 0.98

        //define the points
        let tl = self.bounds.origin //top left
        let tr = CGPoint(x:tl.x + size.width, y:tl.y) //top  right
        let br = CGPoint(x:tl.x + offsetFactor, y:tr.y + size.height) // bottom right
        let bl = CGPoint(x:tl.x, y:tr.y + size.height) //bottom left

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: tl)
        path.addLine(to: tr)
        path.addLine(to: br)
        path.addLine(to: bl)
        path.close()

        //set old background color
        bgc.set()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlgyN.png)

<s>I hope I did understand your question right.
You need to subclass UIView and override the default draw method with your own behaviour. To Adjust the spire you can change the `offsetFactor`
This should do the job</s>

```
class ShapeView : UIView {
    public var bgc = UIColor.clear
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //backup old background color
        self.bgc = backgroundColor!
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.bgc = backgroundColor!
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let size = self.bounds.size

        let offsetFactor = size.height * 0.7

        //define the points
        let tl = self.bounds.origin //top left
        let tr = CGPoint(x:tl.x + size.width, y:tl.y) //top  right
        let br = CGPoint(x:tr.x, y:tr.y + offsetFactor) // bottom right
        let bm = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y:size.height) ////bottom middle
        let bl = CGPoint(x:tl.x, y:offsetFactor) //bottom left

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: tl)
        path.addLine(to: tr)
        path.addLine(to: br)
        path.addLine(to: bm)
        path.addLine(to: bl)
        path.close()

        //set old background color
        bgc.set()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

[Storyboard and Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATOx2.png)

Comment: he meant the white view, not the green picture, but I believe he should be able to derive the right solution just by modifying what you did here

Comment: thank you, I changed my answer to match the question

Answer (score 0):

Dudes, I found an easier solution that works perfectly as an extension to UIView:

```
extension UIView {

    func makeItEdgy() {
       let bounds = self.bounds

        // Create path to mask the view
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: bounds.origin)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - (bounds.height / 5), y: bounds.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        path.closeSubpath()

        let maskLayer = (self.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer) ?? CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = path

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```