# How to apply a downwards curve on a UIView at the top

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uibezierpath, bounds

So I've seen few posts with regards to how to add a curve on a UIVIEW such as [How to apply Curve at bottom of UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317569/how-to-apply-curve-at-bottom-of-uiimageview) but I haven't seen any with regard to how to add a downward curve at the top of a UIView. I have tried playing around with the link attached to this post but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to achieve this curve at the top of my custom UIVIEW.
[image]

Comment: Apply a mask that imposes that curve. The link you've linked to is a perfect explanation. It's just a matter of detail of how you draw the bezier path.

Comment: You posted a link that provides almost exactly what you want. (In the link you posted, the curve comes up from the bottom instead of down from the top.) It's a simple matter of shuffling the coordinates of the bezier curve you build. Post your code in your question and explain how it fails to meet your need.

Comment: @matt in fairness the OP may not understand how to adjust the bezier path to create the curve down from the bottom. He did link the other post and say he was unable to figure it out. To the OP, if you post your attempt at converting the sample code to get a curve from the bottom and explain what goes wrong with that code I'll vote to re-open your question.

Comment: @DuncanC I appreciate the feedback and not jumping to conclusions thinking I haven't tried anything. Anyways I figured it out on my own. If you can re-open it, I'd be happy to add my answer

Comment: have you achieved this..?? If not - shall i post the answer ?

Comment: @SaifanNadaf no need will post answer tonight

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to to do it.

```
lazy var clariQuestionView: UIView = {
    let safeAreaAdjustment = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow}.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0

    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 169 - safeAreaAdjustment, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 169 + safeAreaAdjustment))
    containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    return containerView
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    applyCurve(givenView: clariQuestionView, curvedPercent: 0.2)
}

private func applyCurve(givenView view: UIView, curvedPercent: CGFloat) {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: view.layer)
    shapeLayer.path = self.pathForCurvedView(givenView: view, curvedPercent: curvedPercent).cgPath
    shapeLayer.frame = view.bounds
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    addSubview(view)
}

private func pathForCurvedView(givenView view: UIView, curvedPercent: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))

    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: view.bounds.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width, y: view.bounds.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width, y: 0.0))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: view.bounds.size.height * curvedPercent))
    path.close()

    return path
}
```